# iOS8 Today View Extension widget gives "FairPlay decryption failed" error in app store

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios8, ios-app-extension

Apple accepted the iOS8 update to my app in the app store today, and I installed it on my iOS 8 device to test it out. In testing it worked fine but now the today view extension / widget appears blank. When I looked through the logs on my device, I see the following error associated with my widget.

```
FairPlay decryption failed on binary.
```

I'm not even sure how to begin to address this issue. Does this mean it's a problem on Apple's end, or is it something I can fix? I'm sure I submitted the App correctly because the app update appears in the app store with no problems.

Does anybody have any ideas about what might be chasing this bug? Something to do with signing or provisioning?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem with my app that got accepted today too.

Comment: I had this happen when to me with the Lastpass safari extension. I had to uninstall and reinstall the app to get it to work

Comment: Same here. If you figure out what causes it, please let us know here.

Comment: Apple themselves just pushed an update for the app, and the widget works now. So i guess it was a problem on Apple's end.

Comment: I have the same problem. Is it Apple's bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, this was a temporary bug on Apple's end which Apple didn't announce publicly but eventually fixed, so it is no longer an issue.